# VMWare vCloud Director - Force delete of an object

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vcloud-director

i'm currently rolling vCloud Director and run into some strange issues. 
As you might know, in vCloud Director Provider vCDs use vSphere ressource pools. The problem is that if you temporarily disable DRS in vSphere all your ressource pools get lost, what happend to me. They seem not to be rebuild after re-enableing DRS. 
Now i'm stranded with some old provider vCDs without active ressource pools. However, i can't "change" those old vCDs and add new ressource pools since vCloud Director tells me something like "unable to change vCD settings because something is wrong with the vCD" - yeh, tell me something i don't know.

However: I then created new Provider vCDs and moved all ressources from the old provider to the new one. then I wanted to delete the old providers, which is impossible since they still have 1. a edge gateway and i can't delete the edge gateways since they have 2. a organisation network, which I can't delete because - well: it dosn't tell me why exacly (but no vm's, snapshots or vApps use that network!)

So, I deleted the edge and the network using vShield Manager and made sure nothing is left in vSphere as well. However: the stranded provieder vCDs still show up the network and the edge (which are not existent which is why I can't delete them )

Please note that those objects do not show up in the "stranded items" section, where a force delete would be possible. I just call them "stranded" because vmware is using this term for broken object links.

So, my question is qute simple: how do I forcefully remove a vCD Provider / Edge-Gateway / Org. network vom vCloud director if it's not showing up in the stranded section and normal deletion fails?

I was lurking around the VCloud SQL database but was unable to find the needed table entries. However, manually editing the SQL should be the *LAST RESORT*. I can't belive there is no way to force a object deletion.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a terrible mess, right? Why did you disable DRS? Was there another issue that necessitated that?

Comment: Yes, it's still buggy as hell. Till I got it at a "functioning" level I went into like 20 strange problems like this one, most of them undocumented. Don't want to imagine what happens if something serious happens in the production environment. And yes, i had some issues with my esxi hosts and needed to disable DRS temporary.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Colotti has a blog about doing this very same thing.  Hopefully you have support for this infrastructure as you're probably going to need calling in VMware reinforcements.

http://www.chriscolotti.us/vmware/gotcha-disabling-vmware-drs-with-vcloud-director/

Comment: are you kidding me? can't belive vmware sucks so much nowadays. i remember a time when everything was simply working. time to move to hyperv and system center i guess. well, i'll keep you posted if i'm able to resolve the issue with vmware. some guy from india is going to be pissed off soon i guess.

Comment: vCloud isn't really a native VMware product. You can see how it was bolted on top of vCenter. Let this be a lesson, but the product is going to stay, so get used to its quirks.

Comment: since i'm not in a production environment right now i decided to remove my vcenter from vcloud, reset the vcloud DB and run the vcloud director configuration script again, loosing all vcloud settings. It looks like the "fastest" solution to get a new clean setup. I'll kee you posted on how it turned out.

Comment: Ok, it seems like it worked out. Here a quick guide: first i deleted all ressources which i was still able to delete using the cloud director. then i deleted all remaining vcloud ressources manually from vcenter and used [this](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2033238) to remove the vcloud director / vcenter interconnect. after deleting the cloud director database, recreating it, rerunning the cloud director configuration script and re-adding vcenter to vcloud director, everything seems fine so far.